# Token contract user balance and wallet user balance are different?

Tags: contract-development

I created a token/crowdsale contract using the code from the official tutorial and I set the price per token to be 20 finney. Then I sent the contract 1 ether, but what I got instead was 0.000000000000000050 tokens (in my account). However, when I went directly to the token contract and check the balance using the `balanceOf` function, it shows 50. Is this a display issue or did I do something wrong?

This is my crowdsale contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface token {
    function mintToken(address receiver, uint amount);
}

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    function Crowdsale(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        price = 20 finney;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    function () payable {
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.mintToken(msg.sender, amount / price);
        FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }

    function safeWithdrawal() {
        if (beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
                FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you have an issue with decimal places. If you've imported your token into your wallet with it set to 18 decimal places and it actually uses zero, then your display will be significantly off, as in your screenshot. Equally if your token actually uses 18 decimal places, you'll need to have your crowdsale contract dole out correspondingly more tokens, or you'll be short-changing everyone.

Comment: My token is 18 decimal places, does it mean I have to multiple `msg.value` by `10 ** 18` in the payable function in order to give the senders the correct amount? I tried that, but then the `amountRaised` will have 18 extra zeros.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Solidity does not have floating point numbers, therefore if you have a token with 18 decimal places, your token values are all stored multiplied by 10^18 and this must be accounted for on any front end systems displaying balances.

Comment: If I send 1 ether to the contract, shouldn't `msg.value` be equal to `1e18 wei`? If I have to do the multiplication myself, does it mean the `msg.value` is only `1 wei`? (I was sure I sent `1 ether` not `1 wei` though...)

Comment: The msg.value was 1e18 wei if you sent 1 eth. Your token works in base units. If someone sent a msg.value of '50' to you, they didn't send 50 eth, they sent 50 wei. Equally, and this is the crucial bit, if you give someone a token count of '50', you are NOT giving them 50 tokens, you're giving them 50/(1e18). Internally your token has no decimal places, so everywhere you generate or assign tokens you must remember to dole out tokens at their actual value and not in the base units.

Comment: Thanks! This is very strange then, because I sent the contract 1 unit via the Ethereum wallet, which I believe ether is the only available unit. I would expect the contract to receive `1e18` wei as the `msg.value` and hence the token handed out should not have 18 zeros in front, but this is what happened?

Comment: If you want to give someone 50 tokens, you actually have to give them 50x10^18, because your crowd sale contract does not know or care how many decimal places your token uses, it simply gives out units in the lowest possible denomination.

Comment: My apology for the amount of questions. Since I am sending `1 ether` to the contract and I set the price to be `20 finney`, shouldn't the contract automatically calculate the number of tokens issued for the user as `1000000000000000000 / 20000000000000000 == 50` and issue 50 tokens instead of `0.00000...50` tokens?

Comment: Your calculation is correct, and your contract does indeed allocate a balance of 50. However, this is NOT the same as 50 tokens. It's 50 of whatever the base unit of your token is. If your token used zero decimal places, then it's 50 tokens. If your token used 1 decimal place, then it's 50/(10^1) = 5 tokens. If your token used 2 decimal places, then it's 50/(10^2) = 0.5 tokens. And so on. Decimal places on tokens are like a display hack. They don't really exist, it just means that anywhere which displays balances of your tokens should divide by 10^x to get the correct display value.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you  paid 1 WEI and not 1 ETH. 
balanceOf returns the balance in the base denomination , not sure where you  see 0.0000000000050

Comment: I am quite sure I sent 1 ETH to the contract. For the `0.0000000000050`, I saw it in the transactions list as shown above.